# Operations with multiple dicts

Tags: python, dictionary, iteration

The main questions is how do I have to iterate / indicate correctly to work with two dicts?
I have given two dicts `(d1, d2)` which I have to compare. If the key i is the same in both, an operation is followed due to a given function. The result goes into another dict (`dict1`). If either `d1 or d2` contains the key i, the value goes in to `dict2`. The return is a `tup = (dict1, dict2)`. Here is an example.

```
If f(a, b) returns a + b
d1 = {1:30, 2:20, 3:30, 5:80}
d2 = {1:40, 2:50, 3:60, 4:70, 6:90}
then dict_interdiff(d1, d2) returns ({1: 70, 2: 70, 3: 90}, {4: 70, 5: 80, 6: 90})
```

I am struggling with the correct way to properly indicate the two dicts d1 and d2. Here is my code:

```
def h(a, b):
    return a > b    

d2 = {1:40, 2:50, 3:60, 4:70, 6:90}
d1 = {1:30, 2:20, 3:30, 5:80}

def dict_interdiff(d1, d2):
    dict1 = {}
    dict2 = {}
    for i in d1:
        if i in d1 #and d2:
            dict1[i] = h(d1[i], d2[i])
        else:
            dict[i] = d1[i] #or d2[i]      
    tup = (dict1, dict2)
    return tup
```

Do I have to loop over d1 and d2 (`for i in d1 and d2:`)? It seems like I have to somehow integrate both given dicts to make the for loop work.

Thanks for any hints!

Comment: `if i in d1` - This will always be True. Think harder about what your if statement is doing.

Comment: `for i in set(itertools.chain(d1, d2))`  will give you exactly one of each key in d1 and each key in d2.  No duplicates

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
import itertools
def interdict(d1,d2): 
    dict1 = {}
    dict2 = {}
    for i in set(itertools.chain(d1, d2)):
        if i in d1 and i in d2:
            #whatever
        elif i in d1:
            #not in d2
        else:
            #not in d1
```

`set` gets rid of duplicates.  `itertools.chain`  combines the two lists of keys in the dictionaries

Answer (score 0):

Use [`itertools.chain`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.chain) to get an iterable of all keys in your dicts.

```
from itertools import chain

def h(a, b):
    return a > b

d2 = {1:40, 2:50, 3:60, 4:70, 6:90}
d1 = {1:30, 2:20, 3:30, 5:80}

def dict_interdiff(d1, d2):
    dict1 = {}
    dict2 = {}
    for key in set(chain(d1, d2)):
        if key in d1 and key in d2:
            dict1[key] = h(d1[key], d2[key])
        else:
            dict2[key] = d1.get(key) or d2.get(key)
    return dict1, dict2
```